# Azure Website content or blob storage - which is faster?

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I have a website in Azure which advertises my software. Users can download my software file which is about 100Mb. Right now I'm putting this file in a folder in the Visual Studio project as a content file and publishing it along with the other project files.

Would moving the download files to Azure Blob Storage give faster download speeds than my current approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Geo-redundant blobs are replicated to a secondary datacentre, but unless you use "Read-Access Geo-Redundant Storage" the blob will only be served from the primary data centre.  With RA-GRS you can optionally access the secondary via a different domain, but this will not improve latency for users outside your region.

For best download performance and scalability, store your file in blob storage and cache it close to your users with Azure CDN.

Answer (score 2):

With the file in blob storage you can also get it geo-replicated, so that it's closer to your user. You can also setup a CDN endpoint to that blob storage.

And it will at least make your deployment a lost faster since you will not need to upload the 100MB file ;) (yes, I know, web deploy does not upload unmodified files, so that's not always the case)

Comment: Geo replication of blobs does not put the file closer to a user.  All users will still access the file at the primary location.

Comment: so, geo-redundant and locally-reduntant have the same speed to access?